# Stata - Extract numbers before characters, create a list

Tags: r, list, extract, stata

Good morning,

I have a dataframe where one of the columns has observations that look like that:

*row1:* 28316496(15)|28943784(8)|28579919(7)

*row2:* 29343898(1)

I would like to create a new column that would extract the numbers that are **not** in parenthesis, create a list, and then append all these numbers to create a list with all these numbers.

Said differently at the end, **I would like to end up with the following list:**

```
28316496;28943784;28579919;29343898
```

It could also be any other similar object, I am just interested in getting all these numbers and matching them with another dataset.

I have tried using *str_extract_all* to extract the numbers but I am having trouble understanding the pattern argument. For instance I have tried:

```
str_extract_all("28316496(15)|28943784(8)", "\\d+(\\d)")
```

and

```
gsub("\\s*\\(.*", "", "28316496(15)|28943784(8)")
```

but it is not returning exactly what I want.

Any idea for extracting the number outside the brackets and create a giant list out of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `gsub` to remove the `(`, followed by the digits and `)`, and use `read.table` to read it in a data.frame

```
read.table(text = gsub("\\(\\d+\\)", "", df1$col1), 
    header = FALSE, sep = "|", fill = TRUE)
        V1       V2       V3
1 28316496 28943784 28579919
2 29343898       NA       NA
```

---

Or using `str_extract`, use a regex lookaround

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(df1$col1, "\\d+(?=\\()")
[[1]]
[1] "28316496" "28943784" "28579919"

[[2]]
[1] "29343898"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("28316496(15)|28943784(8)|28579919(7)", 
"29343898(1)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way.

```r
x <- c("28316496(15)|28943784(8)|28579919(7)", "29343898(1)")

y <- strsplit(x, "\\|")
y <- lapply(y, \(.y) sub("\\([^\\(\\)]+\\)$", "", .y))
y
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "28316496" "28943784" "28579919"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "29343898"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>